# Knockoutjs with mapping.fromJS and template

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a table updated with each entry in my model and two events fired on removal and addition to the array. hideElement calls the jquery "fadeOut" and showElement calls the jquery "fadeIn" functions to create a nifty fade-out/fade-in effect.

```
<tbody  data-bind='template: { foreach: entries,
     beforeRemove: hideElement,
     afterAdd: showElement }'>
```

My model is like this:

```
var Model = function() {
self.entries = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
this.getData = function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(response, self.entries);
...

this.showElement = function(elem) { 
    if(elem.nodeName == "TR") {
         $(elem).fadeIn(500);
    }
};

this.hideElement = function(elem) { 
    if(elem.nodeName == "TR") {
       $(elem).fadeOut(500);
    };
};
...
```

The problem is that each time the `ko.mapping.fromJS(response, self.entries)` is called in the ajax response it seems like knockout are removing/adding the entries even if they are exactly the same. Because of that the showElement/hideElement is called and elements in my table are "flashing" since they are removed/added each ajax call.

Is it suppose to be like this or am I using it wrong?

Comment: How are the items in your `entries` collection look like? Do they have some unique identifier, like an id?

Comment: Yes, they have id from an mysql database. The ID is a primary key.

Comment: You need to use the key option in the mapping pugin so that the plugin knows which items are the same

Comment: Adding ID as a key worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the key option in the mapping plugin so that the plugin knows which items are the same

http://jsfiddle.net/yWwfz/

```
var mapping =  {
    items: {
        key: function(item) { return item.id; }
    }
};
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
```

Comment: Yes, I did it like this and it works based on your comment above. Thanks.

`     ko.mapping.fromJS(response,{
   key: function(data) {
       return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
   }}, self.entries);`

Comment: Although if you wanted to make sure you pulled a completely fresh list of items from the server....   wouldn't it then be better to ensure KO completely removes and re-adds all the items?  (Better to not tell KO what the key is?)